# HTML Table -how to put multiple elements into a <td>?

Tags: html, html-table

How can I get "Change username", "Change password", and "delete user" to be positioned inline and get them under the "Actions" category?

```html
<table>
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>Username</th>
          <th>Listings</th>
          <th>Actions</th>
      <tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
      <tr>
          <td>hi</td>
          <td>hi</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
          <td>hi</td>
          <td>hi</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
          <td>
              <a>ChangeUsername</a>
              <a>ChangePassword</a>
              <form>                           
                   <button>Delete User</button>
              </form>
          </td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside `tbody` a `<tr>` should have 3 `<td>` like on thead

```html
<table border="1">
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>Username</th>
          <th>Listings</th>
          <th>Actions</th>
      <tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
      <tr>
          <td>hi</td>
          <td>ha</td>
          <td>
              <button>ChangeUsername</button>
              <button>ChangePassword</button>
              <button>Delete User</button>
          </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
          <td>hi</td>
          <td>hi</td>
          <td>
              <button>ChangeUsername</button>
              <button>ChangePassword</button>
              <button>Delete User</button>
          </td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put them in the third column.

I have also added a 4th column to put your delete user button

```html
<table>
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>Username</th>
          <th>Listings</th>
          <th>Actions</th>
          <th></th>
      <tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
      <tr>
          <td>hi</td>
          <td>hi</td>
          <td><p>ChangeUsername</p></td>
          <td>
              <form>                           
                   <button>Delete User</button>
              </form>
          </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
          <td>hi</td>
          <td>hi</td>
          <td><p>ChangePassword</p></td>
          <td>
              <form>                           
                   <button>Delete User</button>
              </form>
          </td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to work with tables is to have the same amount of columns as you do headings for eg adapting your code above:

```html
<table>
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>Username</th>
          <th>Listings</th>
          <th>Actions</th>
      <tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
      <tr>
          <td>hi</td>
          <td>hi</td>
          <td></td>          
      </tr>

      <tr>
          <td>hi</td>
          <td>hi</td>
          <td></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>
              <a>ChangeUsername</a>
              <a>ChangePassword</a>
              <form>                           
                   <button>Delete User</button>
              </form>
          </td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This will show two blank cells then whatever you put in the third (actions headed) cell.